# 2 layouts 1 activity android

Tags: android

I have a navigation bar in my app, the thing is that I want the navbar to be available in all activities. I suppose that I have to set contentView two times, but that doesn't work, of course.

I've been looking at  and  but I dont get it to work. I have a super class, can I set this second layout from my super class?

Answer (score 4):

You should include the nav bar via `<include>` tag from the other layouts. Setting the content layout twice will not work, as Android is in the callbacks basically always using what the user has told last. So

```
setContentLayout(R.layout.nav);
setContentLayout(R.layout.main);
```

will result in only the main layout being used.

Have a look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) which gives an example of using the include tag.

Comment: do you mean i have to write the same layout in every layout or should i use <include> tag?

Comment: Use the include tag to include the navigation bar. Will update my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend standard activities (Activity, ListActivity, etc.. if you use any others) and use them as a base for including a nav_bar.

For example:

Define a layout with nabar like this

```
<LinearLayout
  ...
  android:orientation="vertical"
>
  <YourNavBarComponent
    ...
  />
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_content"
    ...
  >
    // Leave this empty for activity content
  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will be your base layout to contain all other layouts in the nav_content frame.
Next, in create a base activity class, and do the following:

```
public abstract class NavActivity extends Activity {

    protected LinearLayout fullLayout;
    protected FrameLayout navContent;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
        fullLayout= (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_layout, null); // Your base layout here
        navContent= (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, navContent, true); // Setting the content of layout your provided in the nav_content frame
        setContentView(fullLayout);
        // here you can get your navigation buttons and define how they should behave and what must they do, so you won't be needing to repeat it in every activity class
    }
}
```

And now, when you create a new activity, where you need a nav bar, just extend NavActivity instead. And your nav bar will be placed where you need it, without repeating it in every layout over and over again, and polluting the layouts (not to mention repeating a code to control navigation in every activity class).

Answer (score 0):

Try [merging layouts, as described on Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html).

Comment: This link is broken: 404 Error!!! Can u please update ur answer with any other links?